# eslint error when exporting image - prefer default export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I keep getting the following error when exporting an image in react. The code is as follows:

```
export { default as ArrivalsDeparturesImage } from './ArrivalsDepartures.jpg';
```

but it triggers:

> prefer default export

Any ideas

Comment: Are you sure exporting is what you wanna do? If this is in the file you're gonna use ArrivalsDepartuesImage, use 'import' instead of 'export'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [`eslint-plugin-import`](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/prefer-default-export.md) rule that advice to use default esports when there is only a single export from a module. So to fix it you can:

```
import ArrivalsDeparturesImage from './ArrivalsDepartures.jpg';
export default ArrivalsDeparturesImage;
```

or simply turn it off in .eslintrc:

```
"import/prefer-default-export": "off"
```

od just for the current file:

```
/* eslint-disable import/prefer-default-export */
export { default as ArrivalsDeparturesImage } from './ArrivalsDepartures.jpg';
```